# PyQT badly crashing on a given website

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, pyqt

I managed to create and thread a PyQt application to do some screenshots of a list of urls. It's working really good, but it's always crashing on some websites (or at least on for sure).

[Softpedia.com](http://www.softpedia.com) is one of them. It's just crashing Python with a segmentation fault just before the **loadFinished** event. Even if I don't use my threaded application but "raw" PyQt.

I tested with basic [PyQt based browser I found on the web](https://github.com/Artem-Mamchych/python-PyQt-browser-with-plugins/tree/master/src) and I got the same issue.

Does anybody have an idea? I'm starting to think that this may be a dead end, which is not really a good news.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

There's probably some kind of issue with the the code you are using, this code shouldn't raise errors:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit

class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.barProgress = QtGui.QProgressBar(self)
        self.barProgress.setFixedSize(80, 15)
        self.barProgress.setVisible(False)

        self.barStatus = QtGui.QStatusBar(self)
        self.barStatus.addPermanentWidget(self.barProgress)

        self.webView = QtWebKit.QWebView(self)

        settingsWeb =   [    
                            QtWebKit.QWebSettings.PluginsEnabled
                        ]

        for setting in settingsWeb:
            self.webView.settings().setAttribute(setting, True)

        self.setStatusBar(self.barStatus)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.webView)

        self.webView.loadFinished.connect(self.on_webView_loadFinished)
        self.webView.loadFinished.connect(self.barProgress.hide)
        self.webView.loadStarted.connect(self.barProgress.show)
        self.webView.loadProgress.connect(self.barProgress.setValue)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_webView_loadFinished(self):            
        QtGui.QMessageBox.information(None, "Info", "Load finished!")  

    def loadUrl(self, url):
        self.webView.load(QtCore.QUrl(url))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')

    main = MyWindow()
    main.show()
    main.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/")

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Argh. Thanks a lot for you help. I pasted it and tried with the given website and I still get a "30717 segmentation fault  python test.py". Do you manage to make it work with "www.softpedia.com"? Thanks again for your time!